# Skype  shuts down when the other person tries sharing their screen

Tags: video, skype, logout

I have installed skype on my 11.10 and it keeps shutting down as soon as the other person switches of its video.

While I have read that I need to delete the shared.xml file I cant seem to locate the directory. I have even searched for the file manually.

I installed skype using the software center so I am a little confused as to why I cant find it. every time I go to the home folder it has no skype folder where this exists.

I even tried removing it from the terminal using rm command as mentioned in the protected thread but it only says that no such directory exists.

**UPDATE:**
Ok so I found shared.xml and to my surprise it was still in the same place as mentioned by others, `/.skype/shared.xml`

So i used rm `~/.skype/shared.xml`

It just went to the next command line entry

It didn't exactly return a value but skype would function even if the other person switched off their video. **But when they try sharing their screen Skype still switches off.**

Can someone please help me to sort this issue?

Comment: doesn't anybody have the answer to this problem?

Comment: Some help please?

Comment: Can someone PLEASE help me out with this. I am tired of having my skype switch off every time the other person

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command should do the trick:

```
find ~/ -iname "Shared.xml"
```

If you can't find it there, you can try searching from the root of the filesystem, but this will take longer:

```
find / -iname "Shared.xml"
```